# Iptable order of rules with example

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, filter, netfilter

I had question about IPtables.

Let's start with this example of my book:

> What rules you would set for a mail server accepting connections for
>   EMSTP (port 465) and IMAP (port 993) having a network interface eth1
>   exposed to the Internet and another network interface eth2 exposed to
>   the corporate network?

I tried to respond with this:

```
Iptable -A FORWARD  -p  EMSTP, IMAP -s all -i eth1 -m multiport 465,993  state –state  NEW, ESTABILISHED  -j ACCEPT
Iptable -A FORWARD  -p  EMSTP, IMAP -s all -i eth2 -m multiport 465,993  state –state  NEW, ESTABILISHED  -j ACCEPT
```

- I thought about FORWARD because isn't specified if traffic is INPUT
  or OUTPUT... So I used the generic in/out (FORWARD if I can use in
  this mode)
- The protocol is specified(so I think don't have problems    about)
- I Used two rules because I used different interface, but I    think
  can do all in the same rules, just adding another -i inside the same rule.
- For the network, I think that one is (internet) and another one is
  local network (I really don't know what mean for "corporate")

My question is if my response is good and if it is mandatory to use this type of format.

**What change is I swap the order of the rules?**

In this case ad example:

```
 Iptable -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT   -i eth1 -p EMSTP, IMAP -s all  -m multiport 465,993  state –state  NEW, ESTABILISHED
```

Just swapping the jump and the inteface (-j and -i)

Someone can help to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, some reminders:

- `-p` argument is to specificy protocols like TCP, UDP, ICMP ... not higher level protocol like IMAP.
- OUTPUT and INPUT chains are for the packets outgoing from the machine and incoming to the machine. If you want to filter packets that are forwarded (when your machine act as a gateway), you **must** use the FORWARD chain. To distinguish IN and OUT, use the input or output interfaces and the source and destination IPs
- `ESTABILISHED` --> typo !!! :)

Now, let's have a look to your problem:

> What rules you would set for a mail server accepting connections for EMSTP (port 465) and IMAP (port 993) having a network interface eth1 exposed to the Internet and another network interface eth2 exposed to the corporate network?

The problem is too broad since it says that:

- The machine is a mail server.
- It has two interfaces
- It must accept connections for mail related protocols.

But it isn't said that the connections must be accepted for both networks (internet / corporate). Anyway, let's assume that it is the case.

`iptables` works with discriminants: `-i` is one to match packets incoming to THAT interfaces.
Since you want the traffic to be accepted on every interfaces, then simply remove `-i`.
As mentionned previously, `-p` is to specify the transport protocol. Mails work in TCP, so use ̀ -p tcp`.

So your first responses would work (minus typo and some syntax error, the idea is OK).
Your last won't cause it allows packets coming from internet (eth1) to pass throught your server and go to your corporate network.

Comment: So finally the result is iptable -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT   -p tcp  -m multiport 465,993  state –state  NEW ?  the order of command is the same for first and last sentence? thx for reply

Comment: Yes, but : 1/  put the `-j ACCEPT` at the end of the command line 2/ You also need a more general rule to accept packet that are related to established connection. (since your rule only allow NEW streams.)

Comment: i before used new and estabilish (for new and already existing connection). What is the right command?

Comment: Usually, one put a generic rule for established traffic like `iptables -I FORWARD 0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` and after, more specific rules to authorize establishment of new connections (like the one above). Note the use of `-I FORWARD 0` which mean "insert at position 0" (contrary to `-A` for appending to the end of the ruleset): iptables is iterating over the rules from top to down until one match packet, so always put the more used rules on the top of the ruleset to avoid wasting time an CPU cycles.